# Why does document.getElementById return an object that has a property called 'value'?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and the DOM. Based on some examples on the Internet I have created this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="amount3">
```

Then later in the JavaScript code I have this line.

```
document.getElementById("amount3").value= x;
```

The code works well. I'm able to change what's shown inside that text input. But now I'm trying to understand the underlying code and how it all works. I looked up some DOM reference in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById.

I can see that the method should return an object *Element*. However, element does not contain a property called value. But I notice there is a sub-object called HTMLElement which has a sub-object HTMLInputElement. And that object contains a property called value.

Is that code above somehow typecast as the child object? Why does the value property work as such?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HTMLInputElement` inherits from `HTMLElement` which, in turn, inherits from `Element`.

If an object inherits from another object, then it will have all the properties of that object.

This means that anything which expects to deal with an `Element` can be given an `HTMLInputElement` instead (since the `HTMLInputElement` has all the properties of an `Element`, but some extra ones too).

The object needs to be an `Element` so it can sit in a DOM tree (only `Node`s can do that, and `Element` inherits from `Node`). It needs to be an `Element` so it can have an `id`.

Only some types of element have a `value` property that you can usefully change, so your code also needs it to be an `HTMLInputElement` (or another kind of element with a value property), but `getElementById` doesn't care about that.

For further reading, see [Prototype-based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is what you're looking for.

'value' is a property of the HTMLInputElement prototype:

```
console.log(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
```

The element you returned by getElementById is an instance of that prototype.

Therefore, you can manipulate its value property.

Comment: When I look here I get the impression that `getElementById` returns an `Element.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

Where in the documentation would I have learned that I could use functionality made possible in child objects? How should I have known that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript there is a way to write a code similar to object oriented design.
If you wonder, you can search as JavaScript prototype; (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

HTMLInputElement's parent is HTMLElement;

For example, `__proto__: HTMLElement`

HTMLElement's parent is Element:

```
__proto__: Element
```